# ETH transaction from Jaxx wallet to Binance is still unconfirmed...

Tags: network

Transaction ID 0xa6167ff0addb9e638ac5fc7406d9c238d46c976c37867e6c8700d5cdd3376511.  It's been an eternity, considering how quickly transactions process normally.

Is there network congestion right now?  Did I...do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://www.ethgasstation.info/txPoolReport2.php, a transaction with a 20 gwei gas price (what yours has) is currently expected to take 70 minutes on average.

Comment: Thank you!  I am a supernoob.  And now that I know about that gas station dealie-oh, I can move on to other dumb questions that I will invariably have as this journey through the cryptosphere continues.

Comment: Something strange is going on...

The status of the transaction in Jaxx has disappeared.  But also, it looks like the funds were kicked back to Jaxx AND appear in my Binance account.  So...yeah...

Comment: Just kidding!  Jaxx is just really, really weird.